# Number of enolizable hydrogens in 2-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

[image]

[image]

The number of enolizable hydrogen atoms according to me is four, but the answer given for the question says it has seven enolizable hydrogens. Where are the rest of them?

Comment: Also this book counts also allylic H atoms in methyl group as "enolizable", even if "weakly acidic" would be correct. I have a feeling this site would be better off without all such "book erratums".

Comment: Eureka!! , the methyl group hydrogen are also active  , the double bond shifts towards methyl group when hydrogen is removed

Comment: @Mithoron I don't see any viable way to produce an enol with the methyl group. So I guess this again boils down to some semantics of what was actually asked. It would be nice to at least have a citation from where the exercise is from...